# DAX - formula recursion

Tags: recursion, dax

I am struggling to recreate the following Excel logic in DAX:

```
IF(OR(IFERROR(--OFFSET(F2,,,-4)>0,)),"",D3)
```

Given the data of the index column and the Val column, the index is an index starting with 0, and val is an integer continuously increasing except 0. To calculate the preserveval column,

Logic:

1. From top to bottom, when Val = 0, preserveval = 0
2. When Val > 0, preserveval = Val, and then the following four consecutive values are set to blank,
3. Return to step 1

Examples I created in excel:

[image]

Any tips & solutions would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: recursion is not allowed in DAX. You can filter a table for - more then current index minus 5 and less the current index+5, and go through some iterative function() and if/switch.

Comment: I can't decide whether to leave it blank or keep it when Val > 0

Comment: Ask final user.